# Block user from sending Email to the outside in SENDMAIL

Tags: linux, centos, sendmail, email-server

I have a CentOS server with Sendmail installed and use Fetchmail for mail retrieval. My email server is working perfectly, but I now need to prohibit a user from sending emails to the outside.

How do I allow this user to send email in the local network (within the same domain's email address) but block them from sending email the outside world?

Answer (score 2):

Because what you want is more generic than what [FEATURE(compat_check)](http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/configuration_readme/) does, first make sure that you do not have it enabled in your `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc file`. Then you can write your own version of `check_compat` (note the reversing of the words here). The [sendmail book (4e)](http://books.google.gr/books?id=NQblqMiVqvQC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) has a solution to your question in pages 259 and 260.

Here is a second one: At the bottom of your sendmail.mc file add the following lines

```
LOCAL_CONFIG
Kput macro
D{put1}empty1
D{put2}empty2

LOCAL_RULESETS
STranslate
R$* $$| $*    $: $1 $| $2

Scheck_compat
R$* $| $*               $: $1 $| $>canonify $2
R$* $| $*               $: $(put {put2} $@ $2 $) $1
R$*             $: $>canonify $1
R$*             $: $(put {put1} $@ $1 $)
R$*             $: $&{put1} $| $&{put2}
# Now we can filter on sender and recipient
Ruser < @ $=w . > $| $* < $=w . >        $#OK
Ruser < @ $=w . > $| $*                  $#discard $: $2
```

Here is what happens: The `Kput macro` line defines a map that is to be used when we store certain values in macros. The macros that we are going to use are defined in the next lines and they are `put1` and `put2` with some generic default values (empty1 and empty2) to be used in debugging.

When `check_compat` is called it was a single argument in the form of `sender@address $| recipient@address`. We need to canonify these addresses which in our case means bring them to the form of `user < @ address . >`. You almost always canonify addresses with sendmail before doing anything else. The first two lines of `check_compat` deal with canonifying the address of the recipient and putting it into the `{put2}` macro.

Now our workspace (meaning the string on which the rest of the rule set operates on) has only the sender address and we canonify that too. This means that if `check_compat` stops at the fifth line, its output would be like:

```
sender < @ address . > $| recipient < @ address . >
```

Therefore now we are ready to check any combination we want. Local users in your system are of the form `user < @ $=w .>`. The `$=w` macro contains the value of your domain name, localhost, hostname, anything that is to be considered local, including values in `/etc/mail/local-host-names`.  So this line instructs sendmail that if `user` (where "user" should be replaced by the username of the user in question) sends email to any local user (this is the meaning of `$* < @ $=w . >`) accept this mail and continue with all other filtering activities.  But if said user is trying to send mail elsewhere, silently discard this.

After you are done editing `sendmail.mc` you need to run `/etc/mail/make` to build `sendmail.cf` and the run `service sendmail restart` to restart sendmail with the new changes. Keep in mind that the left hand side of the rules is separated from the right hand side with tabs and not spaces. So **do not copy-paste** the code. Type it by hand.

There is one more rule set above and this is `Translate`. When in test mode, you cannot use `$|` directly. So if you want to test your rules before going to production you have to use it:

```
root@machine # sendmail -bt
> Translate,check_compat sender@address $| recipient@address
```

and see what happens.